# Print Preview Not Showing in Windows 11

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-11

Im struggling with the print preview with windows 11. In windows 10 all print preview work perfectly but in windows 11. Im using .Net 4.8 and load HTM file. I think this problem because Internet Explorer has been switch off, but if im try to disabled Internet Explorer in windows 10 nothind happen (print preview show). Anyone have some problem with me to how solve this?

[image: print preview windows 11]